# Replace some blank space in txt file using PHP

Tags: php, string, replace, aiml

I'm newbie in PHP.

I want to replace some blank space in my txt.file with some word using PHP.
This my .txt file (text.txt):

```
A Chatbot record

Hello, how are you?

I'm Fine
```

**And this what I want**

```
A chatbot record
<category>
<pattern>Hello, how are you?</pattern>
<template>I'm Fine</template>
</category>
```

I already try some code PHP, with `str_replace("&nbsp;","<category><pattern>","\n")` but it won't work, what should I do?

Here's failed my experiment:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("text.txt", "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");
str_replace("&nbsp;", "<category><pattern>", "\n"); //I know it's wrong in here, please help me to fix it!
echo fread($myfile,filesize("text.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

> Thank you, and sorry for my bad english

Comment: is there always 3 lines (and empty lines)?
shouldn't there be a </category> tag?

Comment: Look at using a regex and [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead.

Comment: @IvoP thank you for reminds me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is probably the way to go here.

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents("text.txt");

$replaced = preg_replace("/A Chatbot record(\W+)([^\n]+)\W+([^\n]+)/mi", "A chatbot record\n<category>\n<pattern>$2</pattern>\n<template>$3</template>\n</category>", $string);
file_put_contents("text.txt", $replaced);
```

This can match all patterns

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/95184665ec627cd9354d67853bb696865d51a03d

Comment: `\W` inludes `\n`, `[\n\W]` is same as `\W`

Comment: I've try this, but looks like it never change anything of my text.txt

Comment: @RonAshrovy You can just use `file_put_contents` to put contents back to the file, updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you it work @apokryfos , I actually want to convert a big text.txt file to aiml, is there any loop or something to make it simple? thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'A Chatbot record

Hello, how are you?

I\'m Fine';

$explode = preg_split("#\n\s*\n#Uis", $string);
echo $explode[0];
echo "<category>";
echo "<pattern>".$explode[1]."</pattern>";
echo "<template>".$explode[2]."</template>";
echo "</category>";
```

For me the best way is to split your String into an array so you can work more easily after. Here is the array thanks to `preg_split` :

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(16) "A Chatbot record"
  [1] =>
  string(19) "Hello, how are you?"
  [2] =>
  string(8) "I'm Fine"
}
```

Comment: I already try this but it won't work, my text file haven't change

Comment: Instead of `fopen`try  `file_get_contents` function then at the end `file_put_contents('text.txt', $yourString, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do this:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("text.txt", "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");
str_replace("&nbsp;", "<category><pattern>", $myfile);
echo fread($myfile,filesize("text.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

If you still have issues, it is probably because your file doesn't contain   and perhaps you are looking for \n (new line character) instead.

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("text.txt", "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");
str_replace("\n", "<category><pattern>", $myfile);
echo fread($myfile,filesize("text.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

The problem was that you were not replacing the string in the file, rather you were replacing " " in the string "\n".

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = 'A Chatbot record

Hello, how are you?

I\'m Fine';

$reg = '#^(.*\n)\n(.*)\n\n(.*)#';
$replace = '$1<category>
  <pattern>$2</pattern>
  <template>$3</template>';

echo preg_replace($reg, $replace, $string);
```

A regex can be more flexible than exploding or strpos solutions. (note:  is still missing here.

question remains wether all texts are always on 1 line